Automatic generation of a tracklist for a youtube mix
I'm working on a personal project in which I want to automatically generate a timestamped tracklist for music mixes on youtube. In order to get the tracktitles I'm utilizing this shazam api https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/shazam.
For each song played in the mix I essentially want to get its title (if shazam is able to recognize it) and a reasonable start time for when the song starts playing.
Due to the limited usage limits and efficiency considerations I want to minimize the number of requests I make to the api.
Here are some ways I've thought of how I could do this

Divide the mix into a reasonably sized segments and for each segment, choose a couple of max length clips to send to the api. Then remove consecutive segments that share the same song title, keeping segments that were not identified successfully.
Use some audio AI model or audio analysis techniques to divide the mix into segments, each segment ideally representing a different song. Then handle the segments similar to above.

So far I think I have to go the route of option 1 because I'm not sure whether the process I described in 2 is doable. I'd greatly appreciate any ideas for achieving this task or for potential improvements to the ideas I mentioned. Thanks in advance.
